# strptime error on Ubuntu 17.10 with GCC 7.2.0

Tags: c, gcc, posix, strptime

When compiling a program that uses strptime with the following:

```
gcc http_server.c -g -std=c11 -o http_server
```

I run into the this warning:

```
warning: implicit declaration of function 'strptime'; did you mean 'strftime'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

When I run the program I get a segmentation fault. Upon further debugging I come to find out it fails at the strptime() line. I have `time.h` included in the file. I am also using gcc 7.2.0 as stated in the title. Any help would be appreciated as I'm at a loss.

Here is the line in my code:

```
const char TIME_FORMAT[] = "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT\r\n";
char date[255];
strcpy(date, token + 19);
strptime(date, TIME_FORMAT, request->if_modified_since);
```

Comment: Did you include `#include <time.h>` and added `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE` before including `time.h`?

Comment: Please provide a minimally reproducible example.

Comment: @Pablo Yes, time.h is included and i added `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE` even though i am running a gcc version higher than glibc2.

Comment: Is `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE` defined before any include? I've always had trouble when `_XOPEN_SOURCE` was not at the very top of the file.

Comment: @Pablo Yes it is at the top of the file.

Comment: What happen if you compile this: `#include <time.h> int main(void) {strptime(NULL, NULL, NULL);}` with `gcc c.c -oc -g -Wall -std=c11 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE`? Do you get the warning? I don't, but I get it if I omit the `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE`. Which compiler are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700` on the compiler command line.  Just `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE` is equivalent to `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=1` and that won't get `strptime()` declared.

You could use 500 or 600 instead of 700; you shouldn't need to.

You could also use `-std=gnu11` instead of `-std=c11` and then `strptime()` would be exposed, with or without the `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700`.

You could also think about using a header to ensure the correct POSIX defines are in use; that's what I do.  See `posixver.h`, which is
available on GitHub in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack
Overflow Questions) repository as file `posixver.h` in the
[src/libsoq](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq)
sub-directory.

Comment: Putting `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE` at the top of the main application .c file fixed the issue. I did try using -std=gnu11 with no success.

Comment: If the code is going to last for any length of time (more than a year or so), I recommend against embedding the `_XOPEN_SOURCE` define in the source file.  The number needed will change over time.  It would probably be better to use a header to provide the define (that's what I do now, having been burned by doing it the other way before) or on the command as suggested in the answer.  But for 'throwaway' code, such niceties are not crucial.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the segmentation fault. Unlike `strftime()` you need to allocate memory for the tm structure. added the following:

```
request->if_modified_since = (struct tm*) malloc( sizeof(struct tm) );
```

However I'm still getting the pesky warning at compile time. Ill award the answer to whomever helps me solve that.

Comment: *However I'm still getting the pesky warning at compile time* like I said, you have to declare the macros like `_XOPEN_SOURCE` at the beginning of the file, before any other header has been included. I've had trouble with that in the past. That's I actually pass them to gcc with `gcc -D_XOPEN_SOURCE ...`

Comment: @Pablo Adding the micro to the main.c program file instead of the separate file fixed the issue. Thank you for your help.